# menu is only pulling in one item

Tags: menus

I have an issue where wordpress is only pulling in one menu item on a client's website... it was pulling them all in just fine until recently, so I'm not sure what changed.

This is how the menu was pulling in earlier, and it still does, but now only pulls in the last menu item...

```
<?php 
$args = array(
'menu_class' => 'sf-menu',        
'menu' => 'navigation'
);
wp_nav_menu( $args ); 
?>
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this or how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: A link to the site would be helpful. Also, list what settings you have in the admin area for your menu. Is the primary location set for the "navigation" menu? Does the navigation menu in the admin area have more than one item in it? Did the client mess with the menu? Have you installed any plugins lately that could be messing with it?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds suspiciously like the conflict that happens *sometimes* when tag taxonomies, custom post types, and menus collide in a weird way. I have only found hacks for this issue, and many of them are listed in [this thread on WordPress.org](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-post-type-tagscategories-archive-page).